# How to use Fiddler to intercept https requests from axios

Tags: javascript, axios, electron

I'm writing a crawler using electron which uses Axios, but when I send a request I find that Network in devtools doesn't have my request, so I want to use a fiddler to capture the https request from axios to debug it.

But when I sent the request to fiddler I had problems parsing ssl.
I made sure I turned on Trust Root Certificate,Capture Https traffic,Allow remote computers to connect in fiddler.

Here is my Axios test code.

```
const axios = require("axios");

//get google
axios
  .get("https://www.google.com", {
    proxy: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8866,
    },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

In Fiddler I get the following message.

> A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted
> the parameters below.

Or is there any way to make axios get network information in electron's devtools?

Here's the code I tested in python, and it works correctly in Fiddler.

```
import requests
proxies = {
    'http': '127.0.0.1:8866',
    'https': '127.0.0.1:8866'
}
requests.get('https://www.google.com',proxies=proxies,verify=False)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that the network isn't requesting it because I'm running Axios in the main process and not in the rendering process.

> Running the request in the rendering process and then using Fiddler
> catches the request.